# Any Idea can split out the string with same split syntax?

Tags: c#

E.g. string:

```
  string test= "[1,2,3,4,'Name\'s(w)','ProductName','2013,6,1,10,00,00','2013,6,1,10,00,00',0]";
```

Can anyone help me out with this?So my array should be

```
["1","2","3","4","Name\'s(w)","ProductName","2013,6,1,10,00,00","2013,6,1,10,00,00","0"]
```

How to split the string to array ,string format is like above,value are dynamic.i want the string "2013,6,1,10,00,00".

Comment: I don't understand. What do you expect the array exactly?

Comment: test.Split(',')[6] <-- ugly and not generic but works :)

Comment: Is the format always the same? Are the second and third to last values always the same?

Comment: @wudzik - That wouldn't work, it would just return 2013.

Comment: Which is the criteria to pick "2013,6,1,10,00,00"? the position inside this pseudo JavaScript array? Data format? What did you try so far?

Comment: Basically you want to split on ",", and ignore any commas between double quote?  Sounds like CSV parsing to me.

Comment: yea 2013,6,1,10,00,00 no need split

Comment: Take a look at [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) - it handles delimited fields that have a mix of quoted and non-quoted fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input string looks like array in JSON syntax, so it's enough for you to use built-in JSON parser:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string input = @"[1,2,3,4,'Name\'s(w)','ProductName','2013,6,1,10,00,00','2013,6,1,10,00,00',0]";
            var parsed = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object[]>(input);
            foreach (var o in parsed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
1
2
3
4
Name's(w)
ProductName
2013,6,1,10,00,00
2013,6,1,10,00,00
0
```

Remember you'll need to add reference to System.Web.Extensions in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to match the '2013,6,1,10,00,00' after product name

This will do the job:

```
ProductName','([\a-zA-Z0-9-,]+)
```

you can use http://www.regextester.com/ to test the regex.

To use it in c# you can :

```
private static readonly Regex FOO_REGEX = new Regex("ProductName','([\a-zA-Z0-9-,]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

Match match = FOO_REGEX.Match(inputParameters);

if (match.Success)
{
    GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
    //groups[1].Value is equals to 2013,6,1,10,00,00
}
```

Regards,